# Enabling and Using Recommendations AI on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am trying to find how to enable Recommendation AI on Google Cloud Platform. Unable to figure out how to do this.I have account on GCP.

I have looked for relevant information on GCP, but still don't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Recommendations AI on GCP you should check [this](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/setting-up) documentation along with all the set up process. In addition, [here](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/how-to) you can find a list of how-to guides to get started with Recommendations AI.

Right now Recommendations AI is in limited Beta release, meaning that in order to become a Beta customer you should contact your account manager.

Comment: i have the same issue and when I open the the link for enabling the API, it says ```API solution not found with service name: recommendationengine.googleapis.com```

Comment: @Andrea this is most likely related to the fact that right now the Recommendations API is in limited Beta release, and in order to access this Beta you should contact your account manager if you have one. I've also updated my answer with this info.